# SpringBoot controller redirection doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, redirect

Hitting the `/` directory of my Rest app doesn't redirect to what I what, but just print the redirection directive on the screen: "`redirect:swagger-ui.html`"

My controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class HomeController(val info: InfoProperties) {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    fun home(): String {
        return "redirect:/swagger-ui.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually achieve this without changing `@RestController` to `@Controller`.  What you need to do is return a `RedirectView` instead of a string.  This is how I have it working in java:

```
@RestController
@ApiIgnore
public class ApiDocsRedirectController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/api-docs","/v3/api-docs"})
    public RedirectView redirect() {
        return new RedirectView("/swagger-ui.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works as well. I'll accept your answer instead of mine because it only impacts a single endpoint, whereas mine impacts the entire controller. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Using curl, we see that the answer is text (Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8), hence the simple unexpected text output:

```
> curl -v "http://localhost:8080/"
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: * / *
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 25
< Date: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 17:52:32 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
redirect:/swagger-ui.html
```

The `@RestController` annotation is a specialized version of the controller. It includes the `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations, and `@ResponseBody` is the cause of our problem.

So to fix this, **replace the `@RestController` annotation with the more generic `@Controller` one**:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller

@Controller
class HomeController(val info: InfoProperties) {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    fun home(): String {
        return "redirect:/swagger-ui.html"
    }
}
```

The redirection now works properly.